# Cannot login Ubuntu Core

Tags: login, ubuntu-core

I followed the [install instructions for installing Ubuntu Core on VMWare](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/).

I created the iso and I actually see my hostname has changed. But when I try to login from the console with ubuntu/mypassword I just get wrong login..

Is it possible that I can only login from SSH and not the local console? If so how do I add an ip address to the server so I can ssh to it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 15.04 is EOL and this question is showing up in search results for login into ubuntu-core. 

16.04 and newer support login by ssh key only so this question being open leads to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can login with user **ubuntu** and password **ubuntu**.
There is no difference between console and ssh login.

[image]

Screenshot : login - console

[image]

Screenshot : login - ssh

Comment: I tried that as well and doesn't work either. Also in the instructions its saying I should be able to login with the password i set in the user-data file, but yeah that doesn't work either.

Comment: Unfortunatly i don't have ubuntu on my desktop right now. I'm just trying to run ubuntu core inside a VM on one of my ESXi hosts. I followed the exact instructions for VMWare from my link, and just can't login :(

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to log in to the console. I fixed it by changing the `password` in the `user-data` file to `ubuntu` and not `passw0rd` or anything else.

```
$ cat >> user-data <<"EOF
#cloud-config
snappy: 
   ssh_enabled: true
password: ubuntu
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF
```

Then generate the ISO image as per [The setup instructions you referred to](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/).